# AutoMigrate does not generate self-referencing foreign key

Tags: postgresql, go, foreign-keys, go-gorm, self-reference

I am trying to get self-referential keys to work in my models. For some reason, the foreign key relationship just doesn't get created. I have tried a bunch of variations of the struct tags but to no avail.

I have my own Mixin:

```golang
type Mixin struct {
    ID        uint      `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    Deleted   bool      `json:"deleted"`
}
```

The issues arises in this model, where the ParentTaskID foreign key constraint doesn't get created when I run AutoMigrate on Postgres.

```golang
type Task struct {
    Mixin
    Content  string    `gorm:"not null; default:Empty Task" json:"content"`
    Deadline time.Time `json:"deadline,omitempty"`
    Priority uint      `json:"priority,omitempty"`
    Complete bool      `json:"complete,omitempty"`

    // Relations
    BucketID *uint   `gorm:"not null" json:"bucket_id"`
    Bucket   *Bucket `gorm:"foreignKey: BucketID" json:"-"`

    ParentTaskID *uint `gorm:"not null" json:"parent_task_id"`
    ParentTask   *Task `gorm:"foreignKey: ParentTaskID" json:"-"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this appears to be a bug in gorm. I have created [an issue](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4372) and [a test case](https://github.com/go-gorm/playground/pull/322) that reproduces the bug.

You can subscribe to updates in github.